# $f(z)$ is analytic iff $\overline{f}(\overline{z})$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that $f(z)$ is analytic iff $\overline{f}(\overline{z})$ is analytic.

So let $f(z):=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.
If $f$ is analytic I know that the Cauchy Riemann equalities hold, this means

(1) $u_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)$

and

(2) $u_y(x,y)=-v_x(x,y)$

For $\overline{f}(\overline{z})$ I get
$g(z):=\overline{f}(\overline{z})=\overline{f}(\overline{x+iy})=\overline{f}(x-iy)=\overline{u(x,-y)+iv(x,-y)}=u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y)$.

Now I am a little bit confused on how to show that the CR equalities hold for $g$.

I first tried to just differentiate $u$ and $v$ regarding the first component, i.e.

$\frac{\partial u(x,-y)}{\partial x}=u_x(x,-y)$

$\frac{\partial v(x,-y)}{\partial x}=v_x(x,-y)$

and differentiate $u$ and $v$ regarding the second component

$\frac{\partial u(x,-y)}{\partial y}=-u_y(x,-y)$

$\frac{\partial v(x,-y)}{\partial y}=-v_y(x,-y)$

Now I am not sure on how to show that

$u_x(x,-y)=v_y(x,-y)$

and

$u_y(x,-y)=-v_x(x,-y)$ holds.

In the comments, there was a remark to just replace $y$ with $-y$. Does this mean that I did not need to calculate \frac{u(x,-y)}{\partial x},\frac{u(x,-y)}{\partial y}, and could have just replace $y$ with $-y$ in (1) and (2). And is there an argument on why it is allowed to do that.

Comment: For the question you've asked: replace $y$ with $-y$ in the CR equations.

Comment: @BrianMoehring But why am I allowed to replace $y$ with $-y$?

Comment: If we have equality of functions $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x$ then we'll still have equality when we replace $x$ with $-x$ to yield $f(-x)=g(-x)$.  If it is only true on a restricted domain, you just have to transform the domain.

Comment: @BrianMoehring But what if $f$ and $g$ are only defined on $\mathbb{R}_+$ or something like that.

Comment: "If it is only true on a restricted domain, you just have to transform the domain."

Comment: The question doesn't make sense if $f(\overline z)$ is not defined for any $z$ we're interested in, so I think you can assume there won't be any issues with things failing to be defined.

Comment: Thank you, to both of you

Comment: To elaborate, the more precise theorem is "If $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=z_0$, then $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is analytic at $z = \overline{z_0}$."  Note that the domain is also changed by reflecting over the real axis.  The proof of these theorems must also deal with this domain transformation, even if it's a minor point.

Comment: next idea: suppose you have a power series $\sum a_n z^n$  around the origin, then your double bar expression comes out $\sum \bar{a_n} z^n$  and still analytic, although a bit different if not all coefficients were real

Comment: To recap: the function $\bar{f}$ is defined as $\bar{f}:z\mapsto\overline{f(\bar{z})}$.  So the claim in the title and the first line is false over $\mathbb{C}$.